# Calulate duration in seconds from current time to coming monday 8:29 am in Ruby to Set Expiration Time for a Redis key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting a redis key with a value which would be there not more than a week. And expiration time set to key will automatically expire the key in first monday morning 8:29 am.

For above result, I have to calculate the expiration time in seconds for current time to coming monday 8:29 +0545.

Ex. if today is Feb 24, Fri 10:00 am then it should calculate time difference from today to coming Monday 8:29 am.

I have done some coding and conditions are ready. The time difference only occurs on time objects. Shall I make the coming Monday 8:29 am a Time object with no date on it and make the operation with current Time object?

Any kind of suggestions and help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I have also tried to use [time_diff](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff) gem but it gives difference on time objects only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-next_week

To get 8:29 AM of next Monday you could do:

`monday = Time.now.next_week + 8.hours + 29.minutes`

`monday.to_i - Time.now.to_i` would then give you the number of seconds from now until that time.

Comment: It was really helpful to solve my problem. Thank you so much James. And cheers.